# How to specify column widths in a HTML table so that one column is taking whatever it needs and the other one the rest of the available space?

Tags: html, css

Given a HTML table (100% width) and two columns. How to specify the first column to have the minimal possible width and the second column the rest of the available space?

Since the content is dynamic, I don't have a fixed width for the first column. I want it to be as wide as the widest content. And the second columns hast to take the rest of the space.

Here is two examples of possible data for the table. I need the table to layout as follows:

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+
|just this wide|rest of the available space                  |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+
|x             |y                                            |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+

+-+----------------------------------------------------------+
|a|rest of the available space                               |
+-+----------------------------------------------------------+    
|x|y                                                         |
+-+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you try to use max-width and min width

Comment: If possible, change this table to flexbox. Anyway, if you set the table as width:100% and a fixed width for the first column should do the trick.

Comment: Why flexbox? I want a real table. And I don't have any width for the first column. The data comes from a database. Sometimes the widest value is "abcdefg". But sometimes it is just "ab". And I want the first column to be as wide as the widest content.

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280898/fit-width-of-td-to-its-content

Comment: Do you allow wrap text in table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fit width of <td> to its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280898/fit-width-of-td-to-its-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using   `white-space:nowrap;` on your first column and then setting the second to 100% width?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td:nth-of-type(1) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightgreen;
}

td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>My Content</td>
    <td>My Other Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the first cell to `0%`, then apply `white-space: nowrap`.

```css
table{width:100%}td{border:1px solid}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>just this wide<br>x</td>
    <td>rest of the available space<br>y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a<br>x</td>
    <td>rest of the available space<br>y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```