# Flexbox size child like table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I am facing an issue with Flexbox. I have tried a lot of variants but haven't found a solution.

I need child elements to *stretch* with parent container.

The first row has okay width, but background should also *stretch* dependent on the content.

About second row, background *stretch* is good, but it takes equal width and I need the width to be dependent on content, like *auto* width....

I need it to *stretch* like when using `display: table`, in variant 3.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.row .col {
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row-v2 {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row-v2 .col {
  flex: 1;
}

.row-table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #666;
}

.row-table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Variant 1</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">e</div>
</div>

<h1>Variant 2</h1>
<div class="row row-v2">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">t</div>
</div>

<h1>Variant with table method</h1>
<div class="row-table">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, sit repellendus iste doloremque architecto est et voluptate, blanditiis culpa neque!</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to match that exact, as when a `table` distribute the available space it use a different algorithm than Flexbox, and a more in-depth explanation how `table` works can be found here:

- [How is column width determined in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150154/how-is-column-width-determined-in-browser)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html

---

Simply put, the `table` use each cell's content size to compute the growth, where as Flexbox subtract the content size before it compute the growth.

So to match a text like in your sample 1/2, you need to know in advance if a flex item should be somewhat smaller than another.

Here is 3 samples, where the first use equal growth (`flex-grow: 1`) and the second adjusted.

Stack snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.row-v1 .col {
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  equal  */
}
.row-v2 .col:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1.6;                  /*  adjusted  */
}
.row-v2 .col:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 3;                    /*  adjusted  */
}
.row-v2 .col:nth-child(3) {
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  adjusted  */
}
.row-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row-table .col {
  display: table-cell;
}
.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #999;
}
h3 {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flex - equal</h3>
<div class="row row-v1">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">t</div>
</div>

<h3>Flex - adjusted</h3>
<div class="row row-v2">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">t</div>
</div>

<h3>Table</h3>
<div class="row-table">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">t</div>
</div>
```

---

I recommend to think like this, smaller gets 1, middle gets 2 and larger gets 3, and additionally set `flex-basis` to `0` and solely rely on `flex-grow` defining the width, so a second row will match the first even if its content is different, like a `table` does.

Stack snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.row .col.sm {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
.row .col.md {
  flex: 2 2 0;
}
.row .col.lg {
  flex: 3 3 0;
}
.col:nth-child(even) {
  background: #999;
}
.row + .row {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col md">test</div>
  <div class="col lg">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col sm">t</div>
  <div class="col md">test</div>
  <div class="col lg">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col sm">t</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col md">test</div>
  <div class="col lg">test 1234 with more text</div>
  <div class="col sm">t</div>
  <div class="col md">a</div>
  <div class="col lg">1234</div>
  <div class="col sm">bcd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. and i didn't meant exact.. I just want to filled with auto

Comment: @Kumar I guessed that, still wanted to mention it. Also, take a look at my recommendation, if you intend to use more than one row, or else it won't work.

Comment: Yea.. Thanks a lot for clarification. 
Now i understand how column width determined by browser

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I have added `col-md-auto` class and its css like this:

```
.col-md-auto {
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex; 
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.row .col {
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row-v2 {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row-v2 .col {
  flex: 1;
}

.row-table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: #666;
}

.row-table .col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.col-md-auto {
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Variant 1</h1>
<div class="row row-v1">
  <div class="col col-md-auto">test</div>
  <div class="col col-md-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, sit repellendus iste doloremque architecto est et voluptate</div>
  <div class="col col-md-auto">e</div>
</div>

<h1>Variant 2</h1>
<div class="row row-v2">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test 1234</div>
  <div class="col">t</div>
</div>

<h1>Variant with table method</h1>
<div class="row-table">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, sit repellendus iste doloremque architecto est et voluptate, blanditiis culpa neque!</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As `width: auto` is default you can remove it, and Firefox dropped the `moz` prefix on ver. 21 (is now 56), and if to still use it, you need to add prefix on `display: flex` as well, or it won't apply on those older versions