# How did the browser decide on the widths of these table columns?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table:

[image]

I'm a little unhappy with it, because the width of the second column forces the text to wrap into 3 lines. Wouldn't it have made more sense for the renderer to give the first column a little less width, and wrap both elements onto two lines? Like this:

[image]

Is there some way I've set my table up wrongly?

(I don't want to set an explicit column width because I'm not sure what other content I might want to put in there later. I'd like to work with the browser's default behaviour as much as possible).

Thank you!

```
<table class="sequence">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Rhythm</td>
         <td>Msec</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>8xxooxxoo 6xxxxxx 8xxooxxoo 6xxxxxx</td>
         <td>168ms average<br>(5 tapbacks)</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and css

```
table.sequence {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 320px;
}
table.sequence th, table.sequence td  {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: That's just the way line breaks occur. You will need javascript to change that.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Can you expand on 'the way line breaks occur' please? I actually want to know what algorithm it is using to come up with these column widths.

Comment: I know you don't want to set a fixed width to your column, but what if you add a min width to the column? That way it will still be dynamic up and till a certain point.

Comment: @Corné Thank you, in fact that's exactly what I've just done and it works fine. But I'm still curious what algorithm the browser is using to come up with the width decision it has. I've read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150620/832200 but I can't say that I'm any clearer. Would like to understand the renderer's process.