# html table <td> expands with image, no matter the size of the image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am building an html table to be used in an html email. I'm encountering a weird problem where anytime I put an image into a `<td>` it expands the td(and those below it to maximum width, rendering all columns to the right to their minimum width. The Google Chrome Inspector tool is indicating that the image is much wider than it really is. I have resized the image to 100x136px but the  still expands to 1078px. I have also tried other images but get the same result. What could be causing this? Below is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            table {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 20px auto;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .header {
                height: 150px;
            }
            .bar {
                height: 40px;
            }
            .greeting {
                height: 300px;
            }
            .itemRow {
                height: 250px;
            }
            .footer {
                height: 75px;
            }
            .measure {
                height: 25px;
            }

            img {
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class="header">
                <td colspan="2" class="crest"><img src="crest.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="bar">
                <td colspan="14"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="greeting">
                <td colspan="14"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="itemRow">
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="measure">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="itemRow">
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="measure">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="itemRow">
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="footer">
                <td colspan="12"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is that your actual content? if so the reason the img cell expands is because you have not set any widths and no other cells have content so the first cell will grow in relation to the amount of content it holds compared to the other cells.  If you want the cell to shrink to fit the image, then just set a width that will be less than or equal to the width of the image (or start adding content into the other cells and it may rectify itself)

Comment: This post explains how column widths are determines if you do not apply a width: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150154/how-is-column-width-determined-in-browser

Comment: That's also very helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to the nature of automatic table layout - the cells will shrink and grow according to their contents. But you can use `table-layout: fixed;` on the `table`tag to avoid that and `width: 100%; height: auto` on the image itself to fit it into the cell:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
}

.bar {
  height: 40px;
}

.greeting {
  height: 300px;
}

.itemRow {
  height: 250px;
}

.footer {
  height: 75px;
}

.measure {
  height: 25px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2" class="crest"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x300/ea8" alt="" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bar">
    <td colspan="14"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="greeting">
    <td colspan="14"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="itemRow">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="measure">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="itemRow">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="measure">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="itemRow">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="footer">
    <td colspan="12"></td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I understand that cells can expand based on their content but I don't understand why it's expanding even more than the size of it's content. If the image is only 100px wide, why would it be expanding by 1000px+?

Comment: It *does* work, as you can see in the snippet of my answer, for which I used the code in your question and only added the two settings I mentioned and a "real" placeholder image that can be loaded here. If in your website it doesn't, there must be something else causing it which you didn't include in your code in the question.

Comment: I stand corrected. It does indeed work. I overlooked your table-layout: fixed suggestion in my haste. Thank you for your assistance. Much appreciated.